# Bundler : Is there a way to set the version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

When trying to run 'bundle install', I have this message :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 5.0.2)', in any of the sources.
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "pg":
  In Gemfile:
    pg (= 0.18.3)
    jsonb_accessor (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      pg (>= 0.18.1)
```

Then, I think I need to change my bundler version why is 2.1.2, I would like to change to 1.17.3.

`gem list` command says :

```
bundler (default 1.17.3)
```

but `bundle -v` command says :

```
Bundler version 2.1.2
```

I am using ruby 2.5.1 with RVM.

Do you have any idea how to do so ?

I read that I can use bundle config set but it does nothing.

Comment: Watch messing around with bundle path I regretted that one.  What OS btw?

Comment: OS is Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete manually the directory on your problematic ruby version: for example if there is a bundler problem with the 2.5.1 ruby version, go to this path:

> /Users/YOUR_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/

and delete the bundler directory.

If bundler is in the default specification you also need to remove the bundler associated file on this path:

> /Users/YOUR_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/specifications/default

Then you can re-install a specific version of bundler using @Unixmonkey answer

Answer (score 3):

Bundler installs a binary that gets invoked before your Gemfile is read, so you'll need to remove the version you are using and install the version you want.

You can do this with RVM with the following:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler -a -x -I || true
gem install bundler -v '= 1.17.3'
```

If you hop between projects, you may have to do this a lot, or you can do this:

```
gem install bundler -v '= 1.17.3'
```

And instead of using `bundle install`, use:

```
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

to specify the version of the bundler gem gets used.

I would recommend you look into upgrading Rails, not only to get on a supported version (that has security updates), but it will also allow you to upgrade `bundler` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler -a -x -I || true" returns "Gem bundler-1.17.3 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem"

Comment: Ah, must be a newer version of Ruby that has bundler bundled with it.

Comment: what does it mean ? Could please you edit your answer according your last comment ?

Comment: The `-a` flag tells gem to uninstall all versions, but newer Rubies require at least one, so it complained. I think you'll need to install the version you need, then prefix the version to run like: `bundle _1.17.3_ install` until you upgrade. You could create a binstub or shell alias to make it easier to remember the syntax.

Comment: If you're using Mac OSX:

 `gem uninstall bundler` and 
    
  `gem install bundler -v 'version_number`

Comment: Yes, I installed the version I need which is 1.17.3, but I don't get why the command bundle -v returns 2.1.2. Any thoughts ?